# Windows 10 desktop program that allows for fine-grained calendar planning

Tags: windows-10

I want to do fine-grained daily planning.

The first half an hour of the day might be:

```
7:00-7:15 Showering
7:15-7:17 Brushing Teeth
7:17:7:20 Getting dressed
7:20-7:30 Breakfast
```

Unfortunately, the default Windows 10 calendar app only gives limited space for an hour and not enough to display all these tasks underneath each other with their start and stop times.

I would want the calendar app to still sync with my google calendar. Which program that runs on Windows 10 fulfills my needs the best?

Comment: Not sure what you mean that Windows 10 Calendar cannot show 'em all. Isn't this good enough http://i.imgur.com/heMMLWk.png ?

Comment: @YisroelTech The fact that the screenshot doesn't show any time of when the sheduled events start and stop illustrates the problem.

Comment: you're right, I missed the "with their start and stop times" in your post

Comment: I think you, me and a lot of people need something like this - https://productivity.stackexchange.com/a/16864/5996 - A daily routine enforcer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay (it's like $40) there's a great Calendar program VueMinder Pro. It syncs with Google and seems to display tasks as you want it to. (see sample [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwdTq.png).)

Download it from here http://www.vueminder.com/Default.aspx

Comment: The screenshot doesn't look like it displays the events in a way that's useful (it provides not enough space for the hour to display them beneath each other)